# Find maximum & minimum, and average # of words per line

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble completing a program. I have attempted many different methods to produce the desired result:

1. Create a function named lexicographics() that takes one parameter:

   - `to_analyze`, a required string
2. Using a single for loop, calculate the following for your text:

   - The maximum number of words per line in `to_analyze` (eg, the length of the longest line in `to_analyze`)
   - The minimum number of words per line in `to_analyze` (eg, the length of the shortest line in `to_analyze`)
   - The average number of words per line in `to_analyze`, stored as a decimal.
3. Return these values as a tuple, in the order in which they are defined above.

The desired result should be:

```
 >>> lexicographics('''Don't stop believing, Hold on to that feeling.''') 
(5, 3, Decimal(4.0))
```

However I cannot seem to accurately store the minimum word count. My code is as follows:

```
def lexicographics(to_analyze):
    lines=0
    wordCount=0
    maxWords = 0
    minWords = 0
   
    l = to_analyze.split("\n")

    for line in l:
        lines += 1
        print("line number: ",str(lines), "line text: ",str(line))
        words = line.split()
        print("Words: ", words)
        wordCount = wordCount + len(words)
        if len(words) > maxWords:
            maxWords = len(words)
        elif wordCount > 0 and wordCount < maxWords:
            minWords = wordCount
        print('Word count: {}'.format(len(words)))
    print(maxWords, minWords, "Decimal: {}".format(wordCount / lines), )
     
   
   
lexicographics('''Don't stop believing,
Hold on to that feeling.''')
```

When I test the program, I get the desired maximum & average, but cannot seem to get the minimum correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: What value do you get for minimum words?

Comment: Your initial value for `minWords` is zero, which is probably less than most, and also, you're never comparing your counts with `minWords` in your condition.

Comment: @duffymo I get 0 for the minimum value

Comment: @BenY isn't this:
`elif wordCount > 0 and wordCount < maxWords:`
           `minWords = wordCount`   
a comparison of wordCount to minWords? I'm not sure why the word count would be equal to 0 after iterating through the lines and generating wordCount of 3 & 5.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting `minWords` to a sentinel value initially, and compare them as such:

```py
    minWords = None
...

   if minWords is None or minWords > len(words):
       minWords = len(words)
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this generates the correct minimum word value.